# Adding SearchBar in a NavBar

Tags: frontend, materialize, web-frontend

I want to Create a Materialized Frontend WebPage with a Navbar having static Searchbar placed inside it in the center. Just like in ecommerce websites like flipkart and snapdeal etc. what is the best way to do it using materialize.css???

Comment: did you try anything?

Comment: yes but was not at all satisfied with results